# Insert CSS parent section counter for nested lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

I have a 2 level `ul`. I am using `counter-reset`, `counter-increment`, and `content` to insert a running counter. It works in that the content in the `li`s is numbering correctly.

I have and `a` link in the first level `li`, after its nested `ul` that I want to say "Add To Rule [number of parent li]".

Below is a minimum working example of what I am doing. In the `a` link, it is using the counter for the 2nd level `ul`/`li`.

What it outputs:

- Rule 1

  - Rule 1.1
    ...
  - Rule 1.2
    ...
  - Rule 1.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 1.3
- Rule 2

  - Rule 2.1
    ...
  - Rule 2.2
    ...
  - Rule 2.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 2.3
- Rule 3

  - Rule 3.1
    ...
  - Rule 3.2
    ...
  - Rule 3.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 3.3

What I am trying achieve:

- Rule 1

  - Rule 1.1
    ...
  - Rule 1.2
    ...
  - Rule 1.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 1
- Rule 2

  - Rule 2.1
    ...
  - Rule 2.2
    ...
  - Rule 2.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 2
- Rule 3

  - Rule 3.1
    ...
  - Rule 3.2
    ...
  - Rule 3.3
    ...

  Add To Rule 3

I can't figure out what I need to do to get my expected/wanted output.

```css
ul
{
  counter-reset: section;
}

li
{
  counter-increment: section;
}

.ruleNumber::after
{
  content: counters(section, ".");
}

a::after
{
  content: counters(section, ".");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use two separate counters -- one for sections and one for items:

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
}

ul ul {
  counter-reset: item;
  counter-increment: section;
}

li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

.ruleNumber::after {
  content: counters(item, ".");
}

a::after {
  content: counters(section, ".");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ruleNumber">Rule </span>
        <div class="rule">...</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Add To Rule </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```